# Net current when applying an electric field to a PN junction

Tags: diodes, pn-junction

Can anyone explain to me that why Jn is proportional to

$$e^{-q\frac{Vbi-VD}{kT}} - e^{-q\frac{Vbi}{kT}}$$

instead of

$$e^{-q\frac{Vbi-VD}{kT}}$$

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a short way to answer this but let's start saying why not:
$$J_n \propto e^{-q\frac{V_{bi}-V_D}{kT}}$$

In this case, if VD is 0, the Jn is proportional to "something" and that doesn't look right, as it should be 0.

---

**LONG ANSWER**

When the junction meets thermal equilibrium, the relationship between the "minority charge carriers (electrons) of the p-type region" (**npo**) and the "minority charge carriers (electrons) of the n-type region" (**nno**) is given by:
$$n_{po}={n_{no}}.e^{-q\frac{\Psi_0}{kT}}$$
and for holes:
$$p_{no}={p_{po}}.e^{-q\frac{\Psi_0}{kT}}$$

I will keep working just with the minorary carriers.

But when you apply a forward voltage (**VD**), the correct expression is:
$$n_{po}<{n_{no}}.e^{-q\frac{\Psi_0-V_D}{kT}}$$
and the equilibrium is reached when:
$$n_{po}+n'_p={n_{no}}.e^{-q\frac{\Psi_0-V_D}{kT}}$$
where **n'p** is an excess of minority charge carriers in the p-type side. *NOTE: I am omitting some things here.*

Let's rewrite the last equation:
$$n_{po}+n'_p={n_{no}}.e^{-q\frac{\Psi_0}{kT}}.e^{q\frac{V_D}{kT}}$$

and replacing:

$$n_{po}+n'_p=n_{po}.e^{q\frac{V_D}{kT}}\Rightarrow n'_p=n_{po}.(e^{q\frac{V_D}{kT}}-1)$$

Finally, then we can say that:

$$J_n \propto n'_p\Rightarrow J_n\propto (e^{q\frac{V_D}{kT}}-1) $$

Comment: I appreciate, "In this case, if VD is 0, the Jn is proportional to "something" and that doesn't look right, as it should be 0.". I think "something" component is balanced with J driff when VD = 0, then when VD > 0, we have to minus this component (because it balance with Jdriff from depletion region).

Answer (score 3):

In the 1st equation, the 1st term is drift (current driven by electric field) across the junction, the 2nd term is diffusion (current driven by concentration gradients) across the junction in the opposite way (that's why there is a '-').  You can clearly see that at VD==0, these are equal and no net current flows -- as expected.

Comment: thank you, mate.